# Does flutter_local_notifications have an onShown listener?

Tags: flutter

Since there is a limit to the number of pending local notifications I can create, I want to set only one local notification for a specific time, and when it is shown to the user, to set the next one, and so on. I couldn't find any way to listen to the onShown event in Flutter local notification. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You should include code samples and references to any libraries you are using, your description is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure to show the next notification when user actually sees the current notification. See the below code. The code is taken from `flutter_local_notifications` package.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ...
    _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject(); // user is shown alert dialogue
    ...
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.close();
    ...
    super.dispose();
  }


  // This is where the alertDialogue is shown to the user
  void _configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject() {

    didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject.stream
        .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
      await showDialog(
        ...
      );

      // Now the notification is shown, set the Next Notification
      __scheduleNotification(); 
      // This will be in a cycle, add an if condition to avoid infinite loop of notification.
      // You can pass duration as parameter if needed.
    });

  }


  /// Schedules a notification that specifies a different icon, sound and vibration pattern
  Future<void> _scheduleNotification() async {
    var scheduledNotificationDateTime =
        DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5));
    var vibrationPattern = Int64List(4);
    vibrationPattern[0] = 0;
    vibrationPattern[1] = 1000;
    vibrationPattern[2] = 5000;
    vibrationPattern[3] = 2000;

    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'your other channel id',
        'your other channel name',
        'your other channel description',
        icon: 'secondary_icon',
        sound: 'slow_spring_board',
        largeIcon: 'sample_large_icon',
        largeIconBitmapSource: BitmapSource.Drawable,
        vibrationPattern: vibrationPattern,
        enableLights: true,
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
        ledColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
        ledOnMs: 1000,
        ledOffMs: 500);
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        IOSNotificationDetails(sound: 'slow_spring_board.aiff');
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        scheduledNotificationDateTime,
        platformChannelSpecifics);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: this is only for ios. how about android?

Comment: the answer is incomplete. where the "didReceiveLocalNotificationSubject" is coming from ?